# How to get Apple TV to start an iPhoto slideshow in the middle?

Tags: photos.app, appletv, photo-stream, slideshow

I have a photo album in iPhoto '11.  To stream it to my Apple TV (3rd gen), I open iTunes '11 and do *File* > *Home Sharing* > *Choose Photos to Share with Apple TV*.  I select my photo album from the list and click *Sync*.

Now on Apple TV, I choose *Computers* > *Robert's Library* > *Photos* > My Photo Album.

I see a screen of thumbnails, all photos in the album.  I go to the top of the screen, choose *Slideshow* > *Start Slideshow*, and the slideshow starts from the first photo.

My problem is, I was showing the slideshow to my family (216 photos), and half way through we got interrupted by dinner so I stopped the slideshow.  Later, we sat down again to watch the rest, but there doesn't appear to be a way to start the slideshow from where we left off.

I tried navigating the thumbnails to the last photo we saw, and select it, but that only provides for viewing individual photos and I have to manually next-next-next through the photos to watch them.

Is there any way to start the slideshow from a specific photo in the album?

Any info or suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new album in iphoto with the remaining photos and start on appleTV that album

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party apps now and those make it easier to create and show slideshows from the middle. One in particular that I like is Slidez but there are others such as Storehouse. Go to the App Store and do a search from your Apple TV. Good luck.